# How can I shift the beginning of the graph, so that it starts with a number other than 0

Tags: ggplot2

How can I move the graph so that it has a reference number other than 0? Like this example, where the line follows the value of 3. 
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a bit more information like the code you have tried so far and the results and where it exactly differs to the result you wanted to achieve?

Comment: Thank you. I used this code: guaiuba<-ggplot(date, aes(x = ano, y= cpue, group=1)) + geom_line() + theme (axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 57, hjust = 1, size=9)) + geom_point()
but i wanted to add a line on the x axis to move the results to this new line, like the image i put. sorry if i am not being clear

Comment: I generally recommend against having a low limit other than 0, because the y-scale becomes misleading (sometimes this is on purpose!)  if you really really want it, you can change that with adding `+coord_cartesian(ylim = c(3,7))` or `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(3,7))`. note both are not the same. `scale_continous` will actually remove data points if outside the range